# CSS Values in a D3 Transition box shadow

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I'm wanting to do a d3 transition based on style based in the css. However I am not able to do it for the `box-shadow`. Have I made a mistake or is it not supported?

```
var first = d3.select('.first'),
second = d3.select('body').append('div').attr('class', 'second').style('display', 'none'),
color = second.style('box-shadow');
first.transition().duration(3000).style('box-shadow', color);

.first {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px gray inset;
}
.second {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px blue inset;
}
```

Here is the example in fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zasDK/4/

Here is a working example that works with `background-color` *(I based my code on this one)*:
http://jsfiddle.net/linssen/zasDK/

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are getting the canonical form of the box-shadow style when you are retrieving it using D3. This is "rgb(0, 0, 255) 0px 0px 4px 1px inset" in this case, and quite different from how you specified it in your CSS. Now D3 doesn't know how to interpolate between the strings

```
0px 0px 4px 1px gray inset
```

and

```
rgb(0, 0, 255) 0px 0px 4px 1px inset
```

and nothing happens. It works if you explicitly specify the new style in the same format as the first, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zasDK/10/).

However, this doesn't really give you the transition you want in this case. One approach to fixing this is to use a different way of declaring the style (see paulitto's answer), but this may not be possible depending on what other styles you're using. The second way of fixing this is to use a [custom style tween](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3305854). In particular, you only need to interpolate the colours here as the rest stays constant. In code, this looks like this.

```
first.transition().duration(3000)
  .styleTween("box-shadow", function() {
    var i = d3.interpolate("gray", "blue");
    return function(t) {
        return "0px 0px 4px 1px " + i(t) + " inset";
    };
  });
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zasDK/11/).

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to make transition for shadow color, you can use the fact that it inherits `color` css property.

Change your css to this:

```
.first {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px inset;
    color: gray;
}
.second {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px inset;
    color: blue;
}
```

And animate `color` instead of `box-shadow`:

```
first.transition().duration(3000).style('color', color);
```

See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zasDK/9/)